# How to use Django's ORM to retrieve an aggregation using subquery?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm

Given those models:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    related_to = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='profile')
    # a few other fields


class Metric(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='user', related_name='metrics')
    value = models.FloatField(verbose_name='value')
    target = models.FloatField(verbose_name='target value', default=0)
    date_measured = models.DateField(verbose_name='date measured')
```

A user can be related to another user, as a parent-children relationship.

How to best retrieve all user's children with the sum of their metrics (sum of
value and sum of target) using the ORM?

Something similar to this RAW SQL:

```
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`,
       `auth_user`.`username`,
       `mf`.`meta`,
       `mf`.`value`
FROM `auth_user`
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT `metric`.`user_id`,
          SUM(`metric`.`meta`) AS `meta`,
          SUM(`metric`.`value`) AS `value`
   FROM `metric`
   INNER JOIN `userprofile` ON (`userprofile`.`user_id` = `metric`.`user_id`)
   GROUP BY `metric`.`user_id`) mf ON (`auth_user`.`id` = mf.`user_id`)
WHERE `auth_user`.`id` = 1
```

This does not work (it not produces an aggregation of metrics by user):

```
items = get_user_model().objects \
    .filter(userprofile__related_to__id=1) \
    .annotate(
        meta=Sum('metric__meta'),
        value=Sum('metric__value'),
    ) \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a little easier to think about this if you rename `related_to` to `parent_user` and `profile` to `child_profiles`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='child_profiles')
    ...
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
metric_sums = Metric.objects.filter(
    user__userprofile__parent_user_id=1).annotate(
        meta=Sum('meta'),
        value=Sum('value'))
```